# Проблемы с приёмом информации

Tags: c

Некорректно работает программа.
Неправильно принимает информацию - обрезает первое слово.
То есть: Я ввел 123 123 123 - на выходе получаю: 123 123.
Код ниже:

```
else
{
    FILE* file = fopen(n, "w");
    printf("Напишите здесь нужную вам заметку:\n");
    scanf("%s", f);
    gets(f);
    strcpy(b, f);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    if (strlen(b) > 1000)
    {
        printf("Было привышено максимальное кол-во символов.\n");
        void exit (int code);
    }
    fprintf(file, "%s", n);
    fprintf(file, "%s", ":");
    fprintf(file, "%s", b);
    dd();
    printf("[%d из 1000]\n", strlen(b));
    printf("Заметки созданны.\n");
    printf("Они лежат в одной папке с программой\n");
    fclose(file);
    free(f);
    void exit (int code);
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотели получить вот этим: `void exit (int code);`?

Comment: @Mikhalio, завершение программы: http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/exit.html

Comment: Вопрос уже решён)

Comment: Это если бы вы ее вызвали! а вы ее просто объявили!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое слово читается `scanf("%s", f)`. Остаток строки читается `gets(f)`. Неудивительно, что первое слово теряется. Что написали, то и получили.

Что вы хотели сказать этим `scanf("%s", f); gets(f);`???

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: @Timafiva: "Как это исправить?" зависит от того, что надо получить в результате. Я не телепат.

Comment: Вообще я хочу, чтобы программа принимала фразы и предложения, сохраняла их в переменной, и печатала в файл

Comment: +Проблема в том, что если я напишу отдельное gets(), то он просто пропустит её как пустую строку.

Comment: @Timafiva: Это у вас уже лезут наведенные остатки из того кода, который вы нам не показали.

Comment: Ммм... Ясно, спасибо за то, что указали на ошибку, а то уже долго мучаюсь с ней!